# About an answer for Euler#5 using module "common" ...?

Tags: python, python-3.4

In the projecteuler site for problem number 5, Marcus Stuhr answered with a very great program after used a bit of mathematics and in his program he used this line :

```
from common import primeSieve
```

I have Python3 and I have an error `ImportError: No module named 'common'`

So what I have to use to this program works?

*I don't want to spoil other people with the solution, but if you really need the program I will give it to you.*

Comment: you need to write the primeSieve there is no builtin module or method to do this (although someone may have made a library... its not too hard just look at wikipedia

Comment: I did it, but it was just to be sure it not existed an other way. I will see in wikipedia, thank you :)

Comment: @Shadock if you really want to use a library for this problem then you can take a look at [PYPRIMES](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprimes/)

Comment: `common` is probably a library he wrote himself to hold commonly needed  functions.  Project Euler has a lot of prime related problems, so it makes sense that he reuses the same functions like that.